# React fetch method Delete refreshing page

Tags: reactjs

I'm making an application in react and the browser is reloading after fetch delete. Any tips? Follow codes below. The error occurs when I try to delete a project and especially when I create a new one and then delete it. Then, the message of project included due to a browser refresh appears. From the codes below I think you can find the error, but if you need it, it's on github too, thanks in advance.

````
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

import Message from '../layout/Message'
import Container from '../layout/Container'
import Loading from '../layout/Loading'
import LinkButton from '../layout/LinkButton'
import ProjectCard from '../project/ProjectCard'

import styles from './Projects.module.css'

function Projects(){
    const [projects, setProjects] = useState([])
    const [removeLoading, setRemoveLoading] = useState(false)
    const [projectMessage, setProjectMessage] = useState('')

    const location = useLocation()
    let message = ''

    if(location.state){        
        message = location.state.message
    }

    useEffect(() => {setTimeout(() => {
            fetch('http://localhost:5000/projects', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },  
            })
            .then((resp) => resp.json())
            .then((data) => {  
                console.log(data)
                setProjects(data)  
                setRemoveLoading(true)
                
                //setProjects('');
                //console.log(projects)          
            })                
            .catch((err) => console.log(err))

        }, 300)
    }, [])    

    //console.log(location)

    function removeProject(id){        
        fetch(`http://localhost:5000/projects/${id}`,{
            method: 'DELETE',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
        }).then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(data => {            
            setProjects(projects.filter((project) => project.id !== id))
            setProjectMessage('Projeto removido com sucesso!')
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))    
    }

    return (
        <div className={styles.project_container}>
            <div className={styles.title_container}>
                <h1>Meus Projetos</h1>
                <LinkButton to="/newproject" text="Criar Projeto"/>
            </div>             
            {message && <Message type="success" msg={message}/>}
            {projectMessage && <Message type="success" msg={projectMessage}/>}
            <Container customClass="start">
                {projects.length > 0 &&                 
                projects.map(project => (                    
                    <ProjectCard                     
                        name={project.name} 
                        id={project.id}
                        budget={project.budget}
                        category={project.category.name}                         
                        key={project.id}
                        handleRemove={removeProject}                           
                    />                    
                ))}
                {!removeLoading && <Loading/>}
                {removeLoading && projects.length === 0 && (
                   <p>Não há projetos cadastrados!</p> 
                )}
            </Container>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Projects



import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import styles from './ProjectCard.module.css'

import { BsPencil, BsFillTrashFill } from 'react-icons/bs'

//function ProjectCard({name, id, budget, category, key}){
function ProjectCard(props){
    //alert({name})
    //console.log({category})

    const remove = (e) => {
    //function remove (e) {
        //console.log(e)        
        e.preventDefault()
        props.handleRemove(props.id)
        
        //console.log('teste')
        //e.stopPropagation();
        //e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }    

    return(         
        <div className={styles.project_card}>
            <h4>{props.name}</h4>  
            <p>
                <span>Orçamento</span> R${props.budget}
            </p>
            <p className={styles.category_text}>
                <span className={`${styles[props.category.toLowerCase()]}`}></span> {props.category}
            </p>
            <div className={styles.project_card_actions}>
                <Link to="/">
                   <BsPencil/> Editar 
                </Link>
                <button onClick={remove}>
                    <BsFillTrashFill/> Excluir
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ProjectCard



import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import ProjectForm from '../project/ProjectForm'

import styles from './NewProject.module.css'

function NewProject(){

  const navigate  = useNavigate()

  function createPost(project){
    // initialize cost and services
    project.cost = 0
    project.services = []       

    fetch("http://localhost:5000/projects",{
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json'      
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(project),
    }).then((resp) => resp.json())
    .then((data) => {
      //console.log(data)
      //redirect      
      navigate('/projects', {
        state: {
          message: "Projeto criado com sucesso!",
        }
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))    

  return (
    <div className={styles.newprojectcontainer}> 
      <h1>Criar Projeto</h1>
      <p>Crie seus projetos para depois adicionar os seriços.</p>
      <ProjectForm handleSubmit={createPost} btnText="Criar Projeto"/>
    </div>  
  )
}
}

export default NewProject```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The db.json file was in the public folder. I created a folder called data and put it in it, the refresh stopped... weird... :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `type="button"` to your button element like this:

```
<button type="button" onClick={remove}>
    <BsFillTrashFill/> Excluir
 </button>
```

Comment: Partially solve, after inserting a new project and deleting, keep refreshing the browser...

Comment: https://github.com/dlanger123/costs

Comment: I cloned your github repo, created new projects & clicked on delete. Nothing happens, browser doesn't refresh.

Comment: Do you use chome to test? It happens when create a project and delete... very strange...

Comment: Appear two diferent messages...

Comment: Yup, I used Chrome/MacOS. I also created a new project and then clicked on delete. it never refreshes for me.

Comment: Thanks for your attention friend.

Comment: If you couldn't figure out the solution, you can connect with me on LinkedIn here: https://www.linkedin.com/in/saibby/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why... but if you are putting the json file in the public folder it will always make a refresh to the react application when you make a fetch (Delete method in my case ) it's just weird ... if anybody has an explanation for this please tell us.

now once I moved the json file to the src folder it worked well without any weird refreshes !!